# Measures which cannot be uniquely written as the sum of a purely atomic measure and a nonatomic measure

Tags: measure-theory

[Maharam's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maharam%27s_theorem) says that every complete measure can be written as the sum of a purely atomic measure and a nonatomic measure. According to the paper ["Atomic and Nonatomic Measures"](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1970-025-03/S0002-9939-1970-0279266-8/) by R.A. Johnson, this decomposition becomes unique if we require the measure to be $\sigma$-finite. However, Johnson claims that uniqueness may not hold if we drop the $\sigma$-finite hypothesis. Is this obvious? If not, would someone please direct me to a counterexample?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thank you. I didn't realize I forgot the "\".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Example 2.9 in the paper: "Let $\mu$  and $\nu$ be counting measure and Lebesgue measure, respectively." 
You can decompose $\mu$ as $\mu+0$ or $\mu+\nu$ or $\mu+2\nu$, etc... they are all the same measure.